# Getting the Editable form on click of a Edit Button using ExtJs 3.4

Tags: extjs, datagrid

I'm pasting my updated code here. Please have a look and let me know what mistake I'm doing here. In the form itself I'm displaying the `grid` too.

So when I click on the record to edit, I need to populate the form where I can edit the corresponding record details and update into DB.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    frame: true,
    store: store,
    selModel: sm,
    enableHdMenu: false,
    stripeRows: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    trackMouseOver: true,
    disableSelection: false,
    loadMask: true,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    height: 350,
    width: 960,
    title: 'Edit Contractor Details',

    columns: [{
            header: "Requestor Name",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'requestorname'
        }, {
            header: "Start Date",
            width: 85,
            sortable: true,
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            dataIndex: 'startdate',
            dateFormat: 'n/j/Y'
        }, {
            header: "Supervisor",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'supervisor'
        }, {
            header: "Company",
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        }, {
            header: "Last Name",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'lastname'
        }, {
            header: "First Name",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'firstname'
        },
        sm
    ],

    tbar: [{
        iconCls: 'contractor-add',
        text: 'Edit Employee',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            alert("test");
            var editWindow = new Ext.Window({
                id: 'id_editWindow',
                title: 'Edit',
                closable: true,
                width: 750,
                height: 380,
                plain: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: simple,
                listeners: {
                    show: function EditUser(rec) {
                        var formpanel = Ext.getCmp('formPanel');
                        formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
                    }
                }
            });
            editWindow.show();

        }
    }],

    // customize view config
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true,
        enableRowBody: true,
        showPreview: true,
        getRowClass: function(record, Index) {}
    },
    // paging bar on the bottom
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store: store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No cases to display"
    })
});

//Form Creation
var simple = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    standardSubmit: true,
    frame: true,
    xtype: 'form',
    // id: 'tabForm',
    id: 'formPanel',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 1000,
    border: false,
    bodyBorder: false,
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelWidth: 75,
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },
    items: {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'tabpanel',
        activeTab: 0,
        defaults: {
            bodyPadding: 10,
            layout: 'anchor'
        },

        items: [{
            title: 'New Contractor Details',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },

            items: [{
                //Requestor Info

                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Requestor Details',
                defaults: {
                    width: 150
                },
                fieldDefaults: {
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    labelWidth: 300
                },
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                layout: 'column',
                labelWidth: 150,
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },
                items: [{ // column #1
                    xtype: 'container',
                    columnWidth: .5,
                    layout: 'form',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Requestor Name',
                        afterLabelTextTpl: required,
                        labelStyle: 'color:#000000',
                        name: 'requestorname',
                        id: 'requestorname',
                        //hasfocus:true,
                        anchor: '80%',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        listeners: {
                            afterrender: function(field) {
                                field.focus(false, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        title: 'Manage Contractor Details',
                        // renderTo: bd,

                        // activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
                        defaults: {
                            bodyPadding: 10
                        },
                        items: [grid]
                    }]
                }],

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Submit',
                    formBind: true,
                    handler: function() {
                        var requestorname = Ext.getCmp('requestorname').getValue();
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('formPanel').getForm();

                        if (form.isValid()) {
                            //alert('Tests');
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'NewHireDetailsInsertion?firstname=' + firstname + '&' + 'middlename=' + middlename + '&' + 'lastname=' + lastname +
                                    '&' + 'suffix=' + suffix + '&' + 'company=' + company + '&' + 'requestorname=' + requestorname + '&'...so on...
                                    method: 'POST',
                                submitEmptyText: false
                            });
                            simple.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'NewHireDetailsInsertion';
                            //Ext.Msg.maxWidth =2000;
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Message', "New Hire information Submitted");
                            simple.getForm().reset();
                        } else {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Message', "Please enter all required fields");
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function() {
                        simple.getForm().reset();
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
});
simple.render('mydiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have provided a bit more sample code, as well as ensured that the code you provided was formatted correctly... As so, the example I'm providing should guide you in the right direction if I understand what you are trying to achieve.

It is very messy to put logic into your views, which is what I see you are doing in the code you have provided. The role of the controller in ExtJS MVC is to observe the events fired by views (or other controllers!) and react accordingly.

You can save yourself a lot of time and headache by establishing reference's (`refs`) on the Controller for commonly accessed components. In your scenario, both your Grid and Window would make great candidates for references.

Have a look at the Controller documentation for a more thorough explanation of `ref` capabilities, as well as the Controller's `control` function: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    /** List required views, models, stores here */
    refs: [
      {
         name: 'grid',
         selector: '',
         xtype: 'my-grid' // Defined in the Grid's config i.e., alias: 'widget.my-grid'
      },{
         name: 'editWindow',
         selector: '',
         xtype: 'my-edit-window',
         autoCreate: true // Automatically create this if it isn't already created
      }     
    ],

    init:function(app){

        /** Observe your Views by their itemId or any valid ComponentQuery selector */
        '#my-grid-panel': {
             itemdblclick: { fn: this.onGridRecordDoubleClick, scope: this }
        },
        '#my-edit-window': {
             afterrender: { fn: this.editWindowDidRender, scope: this },
                   close: { fn: this.onWindowClose, scope: this }
        }
    },

    onGridRecordDoubleClick: function(grid, record, element, index, event){
           /** save a reference to the selected record on the controller instance */
           this.selectedRecord = record;

           /** Show the 'Edit' Window if possible */
           if(!this.activeWindow)
                this.getEditWindow(); // Magic method created by Controller Reference
    },

    editWindowDidRender: function(view){
          /** Get the Form by its itemId */
          var myForm = view.down('#my-form');

          /** Load the selected record into the form */
          myForm.loadRecord(this.selectedRecord);

          /** Save a reference to the window, why not? */
          this.activeWindow = view;
    },

    onWindowClose: function(){
          /** remove the reference to the window and selected record */
          this.activeWindow = undefined;
          this.selectedRecord = undefined;

          /** Clear selection on the grid */
          this.getGrid().getSelectionModel().clearSelections();
          this.getGrid().reconfigure();
    }
});
```

Comment: HI JOhn thanks for your reply. But Here im not using the MVC Structure. Everything Im writing in one js file only. I modified some of my code. Can you please check this and let me know: